# Barcode for Crystal Report on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, fonts, crystal-reports, barcode

I am developing an app in asp.net mvc in which I am generating Crystal Reports, on Crystal Reports I am using barcode for this purpose I have installed BarCode font on my local machine and its working fine on my local machine. But When I hosted my application on server and installed font on server, the font is working fine on server localhost but when I access it through URL from any other machine, its not working. Anybody can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barcode fonts on ASP.NET reporting tools like Crystal Reports have such limitation i.e. you **must** install the font on **each** client machine to get it working. refer to font licensing before proceeding. Instead of using the font directly in your report, you should create an image using such font and render the barcode image using a BLOBField. In this way you can forget the idea of thinking is the client has or not the barcode font installed. Here is an [article](http://www.neodynamic.com/ND/FaqsTipsTricks.aspx?tabid=66&prodid=1&sid=68) of how to use images instead of fonts. Do the same with yours there.